# Installing xubuntu-desktop breaks cloud-init (routing to 169.254.169.254)

Tags: xubuntu, routing, cloud-init

Run Ubuntu Server 12.04 (or a later version) in a VM.  Reboot.  Cloud-init continues to work.  Then install xubuntu-desktop.  Then reboot; you will see that there is now a broken route to the link-local IPv4 address (169.254.169.254), which breaks cloud-init.  Details follow.

Here is an excerpt from a successful reboot before installing xubuntu-desktop:

```
...
cloud-init start-local running: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 15:24:45 +0000. up 3.46 seconds
no instance data found in start-local
ci-info: lo    : 1 127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       .
ci-info: eth0  : 1 10.10.0.136     255.255.0.0     fa:63:63:c3:0c:b0
ci-info: route-0: 0.0.0.0         10.10.0.1       0.0.0.0         eth0   UG
ci-info: route-1: 10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     eth0   U
cloud-init start running: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 15:24:45 +0000. up 3.99 seconds
found data source: DataSourceEc2
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting AppArmor profiles       [80G [74G[ OK ]
landscape-client is not configured, please run landscape-config.
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting deferred execution scheduler[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting ACPI daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon[74G[ OK ]
 * Stopping System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]
 * Starting execute cloud user/final scripts[74G[ OK ]
cloud-init boot finished at Fri, 28 Mar 2014 15:24:58 +0000. Up 16.74 seconds
...
```

Now, here is an excerpt from a reboot after installing xubuntu-desktop:

```
...
cloud-init start-local running: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 18:39:24 +0000. up 5.10 seconds
no instance data found in start-local
ci-info: lo    : 1 127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       .
ci-info: eth0  : 1 10.10.0.136     255.255.0.0     fa:63:63:c3:0c:b0
ci-info: route-0: 0.0.0.0         10.10.0.1       0.0.0.0         eth0   UG
ci-info: route-1: 10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     eth0   U
ci-info: route-2: 169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     eth0   U
cloud-init start running: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 18:39:25 +0000. up 5.90 seconds
2014-03-28 18:39:28,821 - util.py[WARNING]: 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [3/120s]: url error [[Errno 113] No route to host]
```

(as you can imagine, lots of bad stuff follows)

What is going wrong here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Check that while installing Xubuntu you didn't installed also something like Network Manager and it is messing with your network configuration.

Comment: Yes, NetworkManager is installed in the final configuration.  NetworkManager does not itself touch the network, it only runs scripts that are configured into it.  One of those is the script that invokes `ifup` on network interfaces.  `ifup` invokes all the scripts that are configured into the relevant directory, and avahi-autoipd configures one (/etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd).  It is that script that adds the problematic route.

Comment: When the VM is supplied by OpenStack Havana (configured in a certain way, all the details of which are not clear to me) and the guest is Ubuntu 12.04.1 then the problem happens.  When the VM is supplied by the latest OpenStack and the guest is Ubuntu 12.04.4 then the extra route is added but it does not break routing to 169.254.169.254

Comment: Well that's probably a bug that existed in previous releases of Ubuntu + OpenStack and doesn't exist any more. I fail to see how we can help you here. Just update (try it with 14.04 + latest OpenStack as well)? If it happens again, maybe use `ubuntu-bug xubuntu-desktop` and let the BugSquad/devs handle it.

Comment: It happens with fully updated Ubuntu 14.04